# mongoose full text-search over nested documents and populate option

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, full-text-search

I have this model

```
/**
* Item Schema
*/
var ItemSchema = new Schema( {
    content: {
       type: String,
       default: '',
       trim: true
},
description: {
    type: String,
    trim: true
},
hints: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
},
status: {
    type: [{
        type: String,
        enum: [ 'draft', 'published', 'vetoed' ]
    }],
    default: 'draft'
}
});


/**
   * Section Schema
   */
   var SectionSchema = new Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Checklist name',
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    hints: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    status: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [ 'draft', 'published', 'vetoed' ]
        }],
        default: 'draft'
    },
    items : [ItemSchema]
});

/**
 * Checklist Schema
 */
var ChecklistSchema = new Schema( {
    name: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        required: 'Please fill Checklist name',
        trim: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
        trim: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    reference: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    hints: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    language: {
        type: String,
        default: 'en'
    },
    category: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Category'
    },
    status: {
        type: [{
            type: String,
            enum: [ 'draft', 'published', 'vetoed' ]
        }],
        default: 'draft'
    },
    sections: [SectionSchema]
});
```

I need to perform a full-text search over checklist.name, checklist.description, checklist.sections.name, checklist.sections.description, checklist.sections.items.content but also need to have a full populated checklist document (nested documents included).

I have try the [mongoose-full-text](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-text-search) but I did not know how to index nested documents nither how to include nested documents (populate).

How do I do this with mongoose-full-text plugin for mongoose or if there is an other option?

Comment: You are actually taking about "referenced" documents, as "nested" means the data is "embedded" in the parent document. MongoDB does not do "joins" and mongoose `.populate()` does not "join", it only emulates this by performing additional queries as "merging" in the client. Either embed the data in the document, or search on the collection with the text fields and then query the parent for the matching sub-document references via `$in`.

Comment: Hi there, Neil, yes I mean neasted; thats how mongoose calls in their documentation (embbeded documents). However I finally found my answer thanks to drewhamlett [link](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1381).

Answer (score 1):

After some research I finally got this

```
Checklist.textSearch(query, function (err, checklists) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
            message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
        });
    } else {
        var iter = function (result, callback){
            Category.populate(result.obj, { path: 'category', select: 'name' }, function(err, catCklst){
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(400).send({
                        message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
                    });
                } else {
                    User.populate(catCklst, { path: 'user', select: 'displayName'}, callback); 
                }
            });
        };

        async.each(checklists.results, iter, function(err){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(checklists));
            res.json(checklists);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would you populate category into itself?